# Combined image rotation & cropping in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, image-manipulation

We currently have a system for cropping images that uses jCrop on the front-end, and `System.Drawing` in .NET on the backend - this works very well, but now we need to introduce image rotation. Only 90 degree angles are needed, and [jQuery.Rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/) works fine in isolation, but I would like to combine these two jQuery plugins gracefully. Do you have any experience in this area? Are there "shake & bake" solutions?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you're trying to achieve? Do you want the user to define a crop rectangle and define a rotation angle at the same time? What is the exact visual result that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Ates,

I'm trying to have a single view of the image, with a toolbar that allows for rotating and cropping the image in a single, combined step.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest rotating the image server side. You really can't combine jCrop with a rotated image, since a CSS-based method would 'lie' about the width and height.

It can be extremely fast. Your UI would simply add 'rotate=90' to the image querystring when the button was clicked, and the image would reload.

Here's a very [simple example of using jCrop and querystring-based resizing](http://nathanaeljones.com/573/combining-jcrop-and-server-side-image-resizing/).

Take a [look at the demo page](http://images.imageresizing.net/JCropSample/Advanced.aspx) to see how responsive it is - adding the rotate command would only take a few lines of javascript. If you need it, I could upload a sample of how to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but, have you checked this jQuery plugin called [CropIt](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/)?

The demo looks very good and you have zoom, crop and rotate in the same plugin, no backend code required.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery pipe-lining is the answer for any jQuery plugin

for example:

```
$("image").rotate(foo).crop(foo);
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work. Both jCrop and jQuery-Rotate make substantial changes to the DOM; they need to integrate in some way. As a last resort I could split the rotation and cropping over several steps, but I'd rather keep them in together.

Comment: Pipelining.. doesn't exist in jQuery. Every function just returns a `jQuery` object.

Comment: for Dykam: and this is what we call pipe-lining :D, you can pipeline more than one operation

for Daniel: you are right, but we still can find a solution... i liked this problem and will post another answer if i find one

Answer (score 0):

Since the two plugin-ins operate in very different ways, I don't think you can readily combine the two. jCrop simply allows you to define a rectangular marquee over an image. Rotation, on the other hand, either uses `<canvas>` to actually rotate the image or the DXImageTransform filter to show it rotated (not actually rotating the source image.)

Comment: on IE Rotation is done with angle attribute, which means you can do rotation and then jCrop

Comment: What angle attribute? The official site of jquery-rotate (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/) states: Two JavaScript image handling implementations are supported:

   1. using DXImageTransform filter for Microsoft Internet Explorer
   2. using Canvas object for other browsers

Comment: yes, and the filter is applied with css, so it's achievable to rotate then jCrop after applying the rotation

Comment: I still don't think that will work. Firstly, the filter is only used on IE. What about FF? Also, if the crop plug-in is reading the image's dimensions, they won't change with the CSS filter; CSS only changes the presentation of the image. If you still think this is doable, I think the onus is on you to write a working demo :)

Answer (score 0):

you may try jquery CropZoom:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/CropZoom

Demo and downloads here:
http://www.gastonrobledo.com.ar/cropzoom/index.html